# Deploying github repo to railway. app resulting - Application Error Is your app correctly listening on PORT?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-deployment, railway.js

There was a solution available on github of adding the variable i did that, what ever i put port number it says already in use, follow is the error on deploy log..

```
   listening on port 9586
   Port 9586 is already in use
  [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Following is the error when i open the deployed link
Application Error

```
 Is your app correctly listening on $PORT?

View the deployment below to check for errors
```

this is the link of deployed repo https://rehub-backend.up.railway.app/ ,
Please do assist if u have any idea

Answer (score 2):

In place of
**app.listen(PORT);**
use
**app.listen(process.env.PORT);**